# Configure the backend of Ipython to use retina display mode with code

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, retina-display, ipython-magic

I am using code to configure Jupyter notebooks because I have a repo with plenty of notebooks and want to keep style consistency across all without having to write lengthy setting at the start of each. This way, what I do is having a method to configure the CSS, one to set up Matplotlib and one to configure Ipython.

The reasons I configure my notebooks this way rather than relying on a configuration file as per [docs](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/intro.html) are two:

1. I am sharing this repo of notebooks publicly and I want all my configs to be visible
2. I want to keep these configs specific to just this repo I'm creating

As an example, the method to set the CSS looks like

```
def set_css_style(css_file_path='../styles_files/custom.css'):

    styles = open(css_file_path, "r").read()
    return HTML(styles)
```

and I call it at the start of each notebook with `set_css_style()`. Similarly, I have this method to configure the specifics of Ipython:

```
def config_ipython():

    InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"
```

Both the above use imports

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
```

At the moment, as can be seen, the method to configure Ipython only contains the instruction to make it so that when I type the name of variables in multiple lines in a cell I don't need to add a `print` to make them all be printed.

My question is how to transform the Jupyter magic command to obtain retina-display quality for figures into code. Such command is

```
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
```

From the docs of Ipython I can't find how to call this instruction in a method, namely can't find where `InlineBackend` lives.

I'd just like to add this configuration line to my `config_ipython` method above, is it possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a Python API for this:

```
import matplotlib_inline
matplotlib_inline.backend_inline.set_matplotlib_formats('retina')
```

The [older (IPython 7 or 8)](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html?highlight=set_matplotlib_formats#IPython.display.set_matplotlib_formats) method is to use the following, but it is now deprecated:

```
from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats
set_matplotlib_formats('retina')
```

Comment: Fantastic. Our of curiosity, how did you find this API? I'd searched in the docs and it didn't come up easily.

Comment: I cheated: I already knew what it was called, so I could search the sphinx docs for the exact name. Adding more descriptive text to the docstring [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/5.3.0/IPython/core/display.py#L951) would help others find it. Notably: 'retina' is not listed there, but it is one of the available options.

Comment: lol...probably because @minrk is one of the core developer in Jupter project

Comment: I tried doing this and I actually get bigger images if I open them in a new tab, but they're being displayed scaled down in the notebook. Any easy way to get them at 100% zoom?

Comment: @filippo you can try `mpl.rc("figure", dpi=192)` without setting `IPython.display`. You will get enlarged figures both in notebook and outside.

Comment: Still works fine. Might be prompted to import from elsewhere now: `from matplotlib_inline.backend_inline import set_matplotlib_formats`

Comment: Updated to the new incantation