# Why does %config line give me syntax error in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I am creating a system in order to predict earthquakes. There's this code in which there is a line `%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'`.
Whenever I run my python code it gives the error as `("% invalid syntax")`.

Earlier I had the problem of `%matplotlib` statement which I figured out through google. But, this problem is sucking me.

https://www.kaggle.com/pablocastilla/predict-earthquakes-with-lstm ("The source from where the code has been taken")

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
from subprocess import check_output
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.cross_validation import  train_test_split
import time #helper libraries
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import newaxis
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from IPython import get_ipython

get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'

# Any results you write to the current directory are saved as output.
from subprocess import check_output
print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

So it is showing "`error invalid syntax` " and the `%` sign before the word config has been highlighted.

The expected output is that I should not recieve an error and any results that are written to the directory are given out.

Comment: Are you running this code inside jupyter/ipython?

Comment: Anything starting with a `%` is not valid syntax in Python. Your question might be about your IDE as @MatiasValdenegro suspected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That % syntax is defining a IPython Magic Command. Read: [Magic commands](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html)

Give this a try

```
from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats
set_matplotlib_formats('retina')
```

Taken from [Configure the backend of Ipython to use retina display mode with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611694/configure-the-backend-of-ipython-to-use-retina-display-mode-with-code)

You need to install Ipython library in order to do this. Also if you get "No module named ipykernel" then install ipykernel.

```
    pip install ipython
    pip install ipykernel
```

Edit: but I highly recommend using jupyter notebooks for example give google colab a try : https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Commands starting with % are not valid python commands, they are only supported by ipython/jupyter interpreter, not by the official python interpreter.